# Finding the last non-empty cell across multiple sheets

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice

I want to write a formula that looks at the value of a specific cell across other sheets and returns the last non-empty value.

For example, if:

- Sheet2.B5 = 3
- Sheet3.B5 = ""
- Sheet4.B5 = 6
- Sheet5.B5 = 4
- Sheet6.B5 = ""

Then I would want the formula to return 4.

Any help is much appreciated, I've been working on this for a while without success.

Comment: Is the set of sheets constant? Or does it need to work with any number of sheets? Does it have to look into all sheets of the workbook (file) or just some?

Comment: It'd be fantastic if it could look at all sheets to the right, but I was planning on just updating the formula each time I add a new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This returns the desired result, although it's not sophisticated or automatic in any way:

```
=if(not(isblank(Sheet6.B5)), Sheet6.B5,
    if(not(isblank(Sheet5.B5)), Sheet5.B5,
       if(not(isblank(Sheet4.B5)), Sheet4.B5,
          if(not(isblank(Sheet3.B5)), Sheet3.B5,
             if(not(isblank(Sheet2.B5)), Sheet2.B5,
                "")))))
```

It starts looking at the last Sheet6.B5: if it's not blank, that's the value to take, otherwise look at Sheet5.B5: if it's not blank... and so on. Finally if they are all blank, return blank.